# Pass html element into method of JS library

Tags: javascript, html

Calling the method:

```
document.getElementById("login_form").initLoginForm();
```

Get Object of login_form in "_myLibraryObject.initLoginForm" method:

```
(function(window){
    function myLibrary(){
        var _myLibraryObject = {};

        _myLibraryObject.initLoginForm = function(){
            alert(this); //get loginform object here
        };

        return _myLibraryObject;
    }

    if(typeof(window.myLib) === 'undefined'){
        window.myLib = myLibrary();
    }
})(window);
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: It's spelt "method" not "methord". I'd edit it but it's only 2 characters and SO requires at least 6 characters in an edit.

Comment: Sorry for the typo!

Comment: Hi :). Can you be more specific about the issue your're facing? It's not very clear to me what you're trying to achieve. What do you want to do and what does not work?

Comment: Hi CodeF0x, I want to access the form object having ID "login_form" within the function "_myLibraryObject.initLoginForm". and want to call it like 
    document.getElementById("login_form").initLoginForm();